# How to refine dataframe so the same output isn't printed each time using log?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging

I have a python program which prints discrepancies in odds which have been scraped from various bookmakers. This is achieved by appending the odds to a pandas dataframe. I want to use a log which records the output of the dataframe, everytime I run the program so that the program does not print duplicate discrepancies in odds. The log would record the 'Horse' column of the dataframe. When the programs prints the dataframe, it would refer to the log to see if there are duplicate names in the 'Horse' column.

Here is an example of the output of the dataframe:

```
            Race             Horse      Bookmaker   Odds  AvgOdds
13     Mackay R1        Which Lily  SportsBetting   2.45     2.04
15     Mackay R1        Which Lily         Bet365   2.40     2.04
17     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Ubet   9.00     7.26
18     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter        BetEasy   8.50     7.26
19     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Neds   8.50     7.26
...          ...               ...            ...    ...      ...
1545  Mackay R10        Cold Power  SportsBetting   8.10     6.39
1547  Mackay R10        Cold Power         Bet365   8.00     6.39
1548  Mackay R10   All Star Rocket           Ubet   7.20     2.98
1560  Mackay R10           Dawlish      Sportsbet  14.00    11.65
1561  Mackay R10           Dawlish  SportsBetting  15.20    11.65
```

Here is the part of my code relating to dataframes:

```
cols1 = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Bookmaker', 'Odds']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols1)
cols2 = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Bookmaker', 'AvgOdds']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols2)
df3 = df2.groupby(by='Horse', sort=False).mean()
df3 = df3.reset_index()
df4 = round(df3,2)
dfmerge = pd.merge(df1,df4,on='Horse',how='inner')
dfmerge2 = dfmerge[dfmerge['Odds']>dfmerge['AvgOdds']*1.15]
dfmerge3 = dfmerge2['Horse']
```

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: Just the 'Horse' column as specified

Comment: so use `dfmerge2['Horse']` like in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you extend your initial data frame to include previously reported events, that gets updated with reporting.

Then as you add more rows, to the data set you can rerun the program without seeing previously reported data.

So given this data (note the extra column, which you will initially have to set to `'N'`):

```
            Race             Horse      Bookmaker   Odds  Reported
13     Mackay R1        Which Lily  SportsBetting   2.45         N
15     Mackay R1        Which Lily         Bet365   2.40         N
17     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Ubet   9.00         N
18     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter        BetEasy   8.50         N
19     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Neds   8.50         N
...          ...               ...            ...    ...       ...
1545  Mackay R10        Cold Power  SportsBetting   8.10         N
1547  Mackay R10        Cold Power         Bet365   8.00         N
1548  Mackay R10   All Star Rocket           Ubet   7.20         N
1560  Mackay R10           Dawlish      Sportsbet  14.00         N
1561  Mackay R10           Dawlish  SportsBetting  27.20         N
```

And using this code:

```py
# Previously...
base_data = pd.DataFrame(...)

# Refactored code from example given
cols_raw = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Bookmaker', 'Odds']
raw_data = base_data[cols_raw]

cols_mean = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Odds']
mean_data = (
    base_data[cols_mean]
    # I assume this was meant to be by race and horse...
    .groupby(by=['Race', 'Horse'], sort=False)  
    .mean()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'Odds': 'AvgOdds'})
)
mean_data = round(mean_data)
report = pd.merge(raw_data, mean_data, on=['Race', 'Horse'], how='inner')
report = (
    report[report['Odds'] > report['AvgOdds'] * 1.15]
    ['Horse']
)

# Filter out any horses that have already been reported on:
pre_reported_horses = base_data[base_data['Reported'] == 'Y']['Horse'].unique()
report = report[~report['Horse'].isin(pre_reported_horses)]

# And then update the Reported column for next time you run the code
reported_horses = pre_reported_horses | set(report['Horse'].unique())
base_data.loc[base_data['Horse'].isin(reported_horses), 'Reported'] = 'Y'
```

New data can then be appended to the base data data frame with `Reported` set to `'N'`, and the report rerun without seeing repeated reports of exceptional odds.

And if for example the horse 'Dawlish' had been your reported, then your updated base_data data frame should now look like this:

```
            Race             Horse      Bookmaker   Odds  Reported
13     Mackay R1        Which Lily  SportsBetting   2.45         N
15     Mackay R1        Which Lily         Bet365   2.40         N
17     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Ubet   9.00         N
18     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter        BetEasy   8.50         N
19     Mackay R1  Molongle Drifter           Neds   8.50         N
...          ...               ...            ...    ...       ...
1545  Mackay R10        Cold Power  SportsBetting   8.10         N
1547  Mackay R10        Cold Power         Bet365   8.00         N
1548  Mackay R10   All Star Rocket           Ubet   7.20         N
1560  Mackay R10           Dawlish      Sportsbet  14.00         Y
1561  Mackay R10           Dawlish  SportsBetting  27.20         Y
```